# Allow user to make email template with dynamic MVC variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I'm very new to MVC 3. My client needs an admin page where she can edit basic email templates like "Dear %FirstName%, Your order has been placed" which I will create. When an order comes in, it will automatically then send an email to the person, using her template.

What I'd like to be able to do, is automatically match up the fields in the template (like %FirstName%) with the model fields of the order, i.e. Model.Order.FirstName when sending the mail. I could obviously use a helper class to manually go and regex things, but I'm looking for a Razor-esque method for this.

I've looked (briefly) at MvcMailer and RazorEngine for this, but can't quite work it out, as those tools seem to rely on a .cshtml file.

Does anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to do? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What you don't understand with MvcMailer ? I'm using it for mail templates and it works like a charm.

Comment: Well MvcMailer seems to be used for views that are created by me. I want to somehow allow the admin user on the site create a view that could be used by MvcMailer

Comment: james - another alternative would be to look at an alternative project (ActionMailer) which may offer some way to inject database objects into the view: http://geeksharp.com/2011/01/26/actionmailer-net-email-templates-for-the-mvc-crowd/

Answer (score 1):

You should consider looking at Fluent Email, which now supports razor syntax.

http://lukencode.com/2011/04/30/fluent-email-now-supporting-razor-syntax-for-templates/